# Difference between multitasking and multiprogramming?

Tags: terminology

What is the main difference between Multiprogramming and multitasking?

Comment: and what does this have to do with java?

Comment: No sorry i m jst asking abt basic difference between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_multitasking_multiprogramming_and_multiprocessing